# Calling tell on an actor with a new properties file

Tags: scala, akka

I'm creating an actor like :

```
 mySupervisor = actorSys.actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class, createProperties()));

    public MyProperties createProperties(){
        MyProperties mp = new MyProperties();
        mp.setParam1("test1");
        mp.setParam2("test2");

        return mp;
    }

public class MyProperties {

    private String param1;
    private String param2;

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }
    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }
    public String getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }
    public void setParam2(String param2) {
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

}
```

MyActor :

```
public class MyActor extends UntypedActor{

    private MyProperties props;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object argMessage) throws Exception {

        if(argMessage instanceof MyProperties ){
            this.props = (MyProperties) argMessage;
        }

        ActorRef newActor = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(NewActor.class, this.props));
            newActor.tell(.... do some work)
    }



}
```

The MyProperties object can change at runtime as it is populated from an external configuration file so to update the actor MyActor with these properties I use :

```
mySupervisor.tell(createProperties(), mySupervisor);
```

Testing this behaves as expected as new actors created by `mySupervisor` contains the correct properties, but is this the correct method of achieving this ? : calling the tell method on `mySupervisor` passing in a new instance of `MyProperties` and also passing in the `mySupervisor` reference ?

Comment: Are you passing a *new* `MyProperties` instance or changing the original?  Complete code samples would really help.

Comment: @Ryan im creating a new MyProperties instance every time. Please see updated question. The properties object is not currently immutable, something I will change.

Comment: Can you include `MyActor`?

Comment: @Ryan ive included MyActor. Apologies if the code sample's are not complete enough. I don't think I can post any more code. I just wondered if 'mySupervisor.tell(createProperties(), mySupervisor);' should not be used in Akka. I will create a slimmed down version of the code if above samples are not sufficient. Something I probably should have done initially.

Comment: What's you've currently posted has one major flaw: `MyProperties` is still mutable.  There's a danger that an instance could be changed after being sent to an actor, at which point you're risking a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  Mark all the variables in `MyProperties` as final and drop the setters and you'll be safe.

Comment: @Ryan thanks. If put your comment into answer I'll accept. Would it not make more sense to have an overloaded method for sending the message to a supervisor instead of passing the the supervisor ref within the tell method ? : mySupervisor.tell(createProperties());